# Запуск bash скрипта, вызывающий последовательно команды php

Tags: php, bash, debian

```
0 13 * * * /usr/bin/fsock -n /tmp/rrr.lock -c "/var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.sh >> /tmp/eshop-amount-import.log 2>&1"
```

файл

```html
 #!/bin/bash
 /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php
 /usr/bin/php /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script2.php
```

не работает вывод script.php

```html
#!/usr/bin/php
<?

echo "hello_world";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

?>
```

и script2.php в лог.

```html
#!/usr/bin/php
<?

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');




echo "hello_world222222222222";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


?>
```

Почему не выводятся в лог echo двух скриптов. Они по идее должны последовательно выполняться.

Comment: а в чем вопрос то?

Comment: @korytoff написала. помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А что выводится в логи? Системные логи смотрели?

Comment: /tmp/eshop-amount-import.log , указанный в первом моем коде вообще не создается по данному пути. 
системные логи это /var/log? тоже не создаетсяя.

Comment: У вас опечатка. Смотрите ответ. Я думаю крон вам об этом сообщил. Крон при ошибке высылает руту почту. Для детальной инфы смотри доку к своей оси

Comment: если ответ вас устраивает, то можете отметить его как правильный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас опечатка в запускаемой комманде. Надо так

```
/usr/bin/flock
```

А у вас `fsock` в кроне. И еще проверьте, стоит ли у вас `flock`:

```
which flock
```

И еще перенаправление `STDOUT` и `STDERR` лучше самого `flock` сделать, например так:

```
0 13 * * * /usr/bin/flock -n /tmp/rrr.lock -c '/var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.sh' >> /tmp/eshop-amount-import.log 2>&1
```

### UPD

Зачем вы запускаете скрипты с указанием полного пути к `/usr/bin/php`, если в самих скриптах первой строкой уже указан полный путь к интерпретатору `#!/usr/bin/php`? Достаточно дать права на запуск и можно запускать так:

```
$ chmod g+x /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php
$ ./var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php
```

Comment: спасибо, пишет /bin/sh: 1: /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.sh: Permission denied

Comment: дайте права за запуск скрипта из под юзера, который его запускает – `chmod +x /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.sh`

Comment: @RRR я смотрю вы любите задавать вопросы и не принимать правильные ответы. Такими темпами вам перестанут помогать. Вот тур про сайт – http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: не то, просто не получается, поэтому не принимаю... Приношу извинения... Подскажите, пожалуйста.  Почему первый скрипт не работает?  Пишет 
"Could not open input file: /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php"

Comment: подскажите, плиз...

Comment: Смотрите права доступа, под кем запускается крон, попробуйте запустить файлы напрямую "script2.php" и "script.php"

Comment: 677 script.sh
Дело в том что выполняется второй скрипт. Первый не выполняется. пишет  "Could not open input file: /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php"
у script.php, script2.php 644

Comment: значит смотрите на права для первого скрипта. Добавьте права на выполнение скрипта для крона – в команду надо добавить группу или юзера "chmod +x /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php"

Comment: @RRR думаю можно для этой проблемы отдельный вопрос задать, и возможно даже тут – http://serverfault.com

Comment: права у первого и втрого скрипта одинаковые 644, потом поставила 77 5. я же рут.
на script.sh права 775
не помогло

Comment: cron запускается то же от рута? Скорее всего нет, а если да, то выполните "chmod g+x /var/www/admin/www/test.ru/bitrix/script.php"

Comment: @RRR, Потом гугл и/или другой вопрос на SO, потом найм сис. админа

Answer (score 0):

в первом и втором сценарии после строки **#!/usr/bin/php** заменить `<?` на `<?php` (интерпретатор указан но не инициализирован).
запуск сценария

> php /путь/к/файлу/сценария

или

> /путь/к/файлу/сценария.

Выше описанное проверял на своем Debian.

Ошибка **Could not open input file** говорит о том что не достаточно привилегий при обращении к файлу. cron есть системный и пользовательский. Логи crona, например, в Debian/Ubuntu можно посмотреть в /var/log/syslog, там достаточно подробно все отображается.

> cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i cron

Добавочка: еще

> cat /var/log/auth.log | grep -i cron